# Converting flat array of objects into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array as below, inside this array creditUsage array has object which has parent-child relationship but all are present at same level

```
    let subCredits =[
{
   creditNr : "A001"
   creditUsage: [
   {
     id: 1,
     parentId :null
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     parentId :null
   },{
     id: 22,
     parentId :2
   },{
     id: 11,
     parentId :1
   },
   
    ]
},
{
  creditNr : "A002"
   creditUsage:[
   {
     id: 1,
     parentId :null
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     parentId :null
   },{
     id: 22,
     parentId :2
   },{
     id: 11,
     parentId :1
   },
   
    ]
}
]
```

I want to transform above array as below by introducing children array inside parent one

```
let subCredit = [
{
   creditNr : "A001"
   creditUsage:[
   {
     id: 1,
     parentId :null
     children:[
       {id: 11,
        parentId :1}
       ]
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     parentId :null
     children:[
       {id: 22,
        parentId :2}
       ]
    }
   ]
},
]
```

I'm filtering all rootCredits and storing it first then trying to add children nodes to it, but couldn't achieve

```
export const displayCredit(subCredits)=>
{

let root = filterRootCredits(subCredits);
let usage=[];
 const treeData = root.map(r=>{
   subCredits.map(s=>{
   usage = r.creditUsage.map(node => {
   const children =s.creditUsages.filter(item=>item.parentId ===node.id).map(item =>{return item;})
return {

...node,
children
}
})
})
return subCredit;
})
 
return treeData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily with a recursive function (akin reduce, with an accumulator).

This is a pretty rush draft:

```
function nest_them(creds, acc) {
    if (creds.length == 0) {
      return acc
    }
    var [c, ...rest] = creds
    if (c.parentId) {
      let parent = acc.find(x => x.id == c.parentId);
      (parent.children = parent.children || []).push(c)
      return nest_them(rest, acc)
    } else {
      return nest_them(rest, [...acc, c])
    }
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
subCredits.map(x => ({...x, creditUsage: nest_them(x.creditUsage, [])}))
```